# toString() with and without parameter

Tags: java, tostring

I don't know how to write my `toString()` method.

This is my Main.java

```
Dice d = new Dice();
System.out.println(d);

d= new Dice(3);
System.out.println(d);
```

How should I write my `toString()` method, do I need to write two toString()'s ?

My `Dice()`:

```
public class Dice {

    private double kz= Math.random() * (6 - 1) + 1;
    private double mz;

    public Dice() {
        this.kz= Math.random() * (6 - 1) + 1;
    }

    public Dice(double n) {
        this.mz= n;
    }

    public String toString() {
            return String.format("%.0f", this.kz);
    }

}
```

I tried it with this, but it's not working

```
public String toString(double i) {
    return String.format("%.0f", this.mz);
}
```

Comment: What is mean two toString()?

Comment: It's not clear what you were expecting the version with the parameter to do, or why it occurred to you to write it that way. But in general, to override a method, your method needs to have the same signature as the method you're overriding. As you'll see from the definition of Object.toString(), that means no parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having two separate members for the two constructors, you could use the same member. This way, your `toString` method doesn't need to try and figure out how the object was constructed:

```java
public class Dice {

    private double kz;

    public Dice() {
        this(Math.random() * (6 - 1) + 1);
    }

    public Dice(double n) {
        this.kz = n;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.0f", this.kz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `toString()` method is the default method that is called most of built-in java classes and it's a standard for returning object information as a string.

Your method:

```
public String toString(double i) {
    return String.format("%.0f", this.mz);
}
```

isn't working because by convention methods like `Stystem.out.println()` will look for the standard signature, not a weird `toString(doulbe foo)`.

If you want to see your object state at the method call you can do something like this:

```
public String toString(double i) {
    return String.format("kz = %.0f, mz = %.0f, ", kz, mz);
}
```

There are some tweaks that you can make to your Dice class:

- You can also omit the this keyword, you have to use when you want to reference the same object you are in or when there are conflicts like this:

  ```
  public class Dice {

      private double foo;

      // If you try to remove this. you will get a runtime error
      public Dice(double foo) {
          this.foo = foo;
      }
  }
  ```
- You can have only one variable and multiple constructors that calls themself (credit to [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65782513/14626710)):

  ```
  public class Dice {
      private double kz;

      public Dice() {
          this(Math.random() * (6 - 1) + 1);
      }

      public Dice(double n) {
          this.kz = n;
      }
  }
  ```